# How to save multiple text inputs to Core Data with multiple rows in sections?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

[image]

Okay so I'm making a app for fun to get a hang of things. This app is supposed to allow a user to input the number of times he or she has been paid from a client and which account/card number he or she used for the payment. The way I have this set up in CoreData is I have an entity for Client which contains:

- details
- name
- entryId
- sectionId
- numberOfPayments

details is another cell type that I lets out in the picture that allows the user to input details about the client. I also have an entity for Payments that acts as a many to one relationship to Client that holds the amount and account number given that there can be many.

What I have trouble with is accessing the tableview to save all the data when the done button is hit. I was thinking about a nested for loop that would go through each section and for each row it will save the data accordingly like for Rob through an if statement it will know the first row is a part of the Client entity and every row after would be apart of the Payments entity as relationships. How would I access these individual cells? Is it possible to have this much flexibility with TableView or should I take a different approach.

Comment: I'd say anything that requires you to pull data out of UI elements to save it has a structure problem.  The table should be just for user interaction.  You should have a data model (array of Client?) that is the authoritative source of most-current edits.  Save it rather than referencing cells.

Comment: Wouldn't the most-current edits be what was edited in each cell though?

Comment: If you update your backing data to match each edit as it happens, it's safer as well as making the saves easy.  For example, if I type something in a cell then scroll away from it, that cell can get reused for a different table position.

Comment: As in that cell can be used as a whole different cell? How is that possible?

Comment: Commonly, people prepare cells to show by calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.  Note the word "Reusable".  `UITableView` has a cache of cells and either gives you a new one or one from the cache if you specify the same identifier.  Cells are intended only as visual elements so the assumption is that you'll keep your data somewhere else and just tell the cell what to show when your data source is asked for it.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I still have a lot of learning to do I see. I'm new to ios development. So would you also advise me to take a different approach to how the users add and interact with the table I created. My approach was to allow the user to input numerous clients. So they would enter the names which would be added to an array, then the UITable would take those names and create sections for the clients like you see in the picture. And then the user would be able to manipulate how many rows there are.

Comment: Following what you said that might be a bad idea to allow the users to manipulate it like that correct? Because multiple cells can appear and disappear given the users input which may cause problems deleting and inserting new entity objects. @PhillipMills

Comment: I don't think there's anything fundamentally wrong with your UI ideas.  You only need to remember that the purpose of the UI is to be a "picture" of some subset of the data.  Make sure that the data is always correct and use it to feed the UI as needed, not depending on UI elements as storage.

Comment: Oh okay I see what you are saying now that makes a lot of sense. I'll think this through and figure out a better way to save everything without the user having to use a lot of individualized elements. I can see what type of problems that cause. Thank you!